# Difference between Data_Wrap_Struct and TypedData_Wrap_Struct?

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I'm wrapping a C struct in a Ruby C extension but I can't find the differente between Data_Wrap_Struct and TypedData_Wrap_Struct in the docs, what's the difference between the two functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's described pretty well in the [official documentation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/96db72ce38b27799dd8e80ca00696e41234db6ba/doc/extension.rdoc#encapsulate-c-data-into-a-ruby-object).

The tl;dr is that `Data_Wrap_Struct` is deprecated and just lets you set the class and the mark/free functions for the wrapped data. `TypedData_Wrap_Struct` instead lets you set the class and then takes a pointer to a `rb_data_type_struct` structure that allows for more advanced options to be set for the wrapping:

- the mark/free functions as before, but also
- an internal label to identify the wrapped type
- a function for calculating memory consumption
- arbitrary data (basically letting you wrap data at a class level)
- additional flags for garbage collection optimization

Check my [unofficial documentation](http://silverhammermba.github.io/emberb/c/#data) for a couple examples of how this is used.